# how to programming load router in angular

Tags: angular, routes

in our angular project, we want to dynamically load setup routes in the code.
in the AppComponent file, we add like below  but it not work.

previous version of angular 7.2 can work ,but after angular 8 ,it seems not work.

I dont know how to make it work.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

 constructor(private route: Router){

 }
 ngOnInit(){

  let routes = this.route.config;
   routes.push({ path: 'sample', component: sampleComponent });

 }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig ; maybe not working well with lazy-loaded modules

Comment: thanks to reply after I did this ,gotERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for sampleComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?